# How to integrate all the classifiers for multilabel svm classification

Tags: python, nlp, svm

I have 4 labelled groups which I want to classify using SVM.

```
Class-A, Class-B, Class-C, Class-D
```

Now If I need to train my classifier to recognize I will copy all the text from A,B,C,D into a file "`A-against-all`". SImilarly for B,C & D as

```
"B-against-all" CLass B :1 , Rest all :-1
"C-against-all" CLass C :1 , Rest all :-1
"D-against-all" CLass D :1 , Rest all :-1
```

Now if I run SVM on "`A-against-all`" then I get a classifier as output.
Similarly I get three more classifiers for B,C & D.

Now my questions is this : - How do I integrate these 4 classifiers so as to operate in unison ?

Comment: I guess the OP meant to say that the file "B-against-all" will have class-B as 1 and rest all as -1, similarly "C-against-all" will have class-C as 1 and rest all as -1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to merge 2 or more SVM classifiers into 1. But for your particular problem you can get a desired SVM by creating a file containing all data of A, B, C & D with separate labels say `1,2,3 & 4` respectively for `A, B, C & D`. Run SVM on this combined file and and the generated classifier will correctly identify a data point to be of Class-A, Class-B, Class-C or Class-D.

SVM on iris data. Iris data has three classes 0,1,2. 0-50 are class-0, 50-100 are class-1 and 100-150 are class-2.

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets as DS
>>> iris = DS.load_iris()
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> clf=svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(iris.data,iris.target)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> clf.predict(iris.data[25])
array([0])
>>> clf.predict(iris.data[75])
array([1])
>>> clf.predict(iris.data[125])
array([2])
```

As you can see SVM has classified data with three class labels and predicted accurately.

Have a look at this question: [Prepare data for text classification using Scikit Learn SVM.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942744/prepare-data-for-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-svm) This is what you need to do.

Comment: But doesnt SVM operate on binary classification only ? Are you sure it will work?

Comment: SVM doesn't operate on binary classification only. It can classify with any number of classes. Try it this way. It will work definitely.

Comment: I've uploaded code where SVM accurately classifies data with three classes. Check it.

Comment: @rzach you should also refer http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/ as suggested by bhat

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD thanks a lot. But how do I prepare my data for svm. Actually my data is text data. Classes : "pharma","retail","food&travel". I have 100 text files for each of these classes. Now how do I convert these text files so as to be used in SVM?

Comment: @rzach I've provided a link in my answer where you can find the solution of text classification using SVM.

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD can you please also answer this (nobody has answered it yet) ,wont take much of you time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201418/data-preparation-feature-selection-for-named-entity-using-svm